# Error encountered while Dust Integration with Express

Tags: node.js, express, integration, dust.js

I am trying to integrate Dust with node.js. I am using Express as node.js framework.
I created an express project with following command.

```
    express test  
    npm install -d
```

Then i installed dust using command

```
    npm install dust
```

Then i changed my view engine from 'jade' to 'dust' in app.js file.
I created two views named as index.dust in my views folder containing the following code:

```
    {<title}Homepage{/title}
    {<page_id}index{/page_id}
    {<main}
        Homepage content goes here
    {/main}
```

now when I run my project using node monitor in following command:

```
    nodemon app.js
```

it throws me following error:

500 Error: require.paths is removed. Use node_modules folders, or the NODE_PATH environment variable instead.

```
at Function.Module._compile.Object.defineProperty.get (module.js:386:11)
at Object. (C:\testExpress\node_modules\dust\lib\server.js:6:8)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at Object. (C:\testExpress\node_modules\dust\lib\dust.js:511:7)
at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

Please help me in resolving it. I am a newbie on node.js, express and dust.

Comment: It looks like the version of dust you're using was written for an older version of node and uses now-abandoned syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dustjs no longer seems to be maintained. Use the linkedin fork. https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/akdubya/dustjs/issues/43) with dust; it's written to use a now-abandoned version of node's module system. The issue page shows some people's workarounds.